# After Conversion of GLsurfaceview (bitmap) to pdf file , some other colors in the image is missing, in android Opengles2.0

Tags: android, pdf-generation, opengl-es-2.0, glsurfaceview

I am developing Like an autocad app like an desktop in android using OpenGL ES2.0 .  I am drawn some objects in GLSurfaceview,like lines, cirles, and linear dimensioning etc. After drawn objects on GLSurfaceview. i am capture screen of the GLSurfaceview and make the PDF File Conversion. then, open the pdf file, some objects are misssing....

This is my output First-image : my Original output , Second-image : PDF File output...

[image: Original Output]

[image: PDF File Output]

My Code:

**Note:** In this code, when i click the button, it will take the screenshot as image and save in sdcard location. i used Boolean condition in ondraw method if condition, why because, renderer class, ondraw method is calling anytime, anyway, this code executed without boolean condition, it saved lots of images in memory card, that's why i put this boolean condition.

MainActivity Class :

```
protected boolean printOptionEnable = false;

saveImageButton.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
      Log.v("hari", "pan button clicked");
      isSaveClick = true;
      myRenderer.printOptionEnable = isSaveClick;
   }
} );
```

MyRenderer Class :

```
int width_surface , height_surface ;
@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
   Log.i("JO", "onSurfaceChanged");
   // Adjust the viewport based on geometry changes,
   // such as screen rotation
   GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

   float ratio = (float) width / height;

   width_surface =  width ;
   height_surface = height ;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------

@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {

   try {
      if ( printOptionEnable )  {
         printOptionEnable = false ;
         Log.i("hari", "printOptionEnable if condition:"+printOptionEnable);
         int w = width_surface ;
         int h = height_surface  ;

         Log.i("hari", "w:"+w+"-----h:"+h);

         int b[]=new int[(int) (w*h)];
         int bt[]=new int[(int) (w*h)];
         IntBuffer buffer=IntBuffer.wrap(b);
         buffer.position(0);
         GLES20.glReadPixels(0, 0, w, h,GLES20.GL_RGBA,GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
         for(int i=0; i<h; i++)
         {
            //remember, that OpenGL bitmap is incompatible with Android bitmap
            //and so, some correction need.        
            for(int j=0; j<w; j++)
            {
               int pix=b[i*w+j];
               int pb=(pix>>16)&0xff;
               int pr=(pix<<16)&0x00ff0000;
               int pix1=(pix&0xff00ff00) | pr | pb;
               bt[(h-i-1)*w+j]=pix1;
            }
         }           
         Bitmap inBitmap = null ;
         if ( inBitmap == null || !inBitmap.isMutable() ||
              inBitmap.getWidth() != w || inBitmap.getHeight() != h) {
            inBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
         }
         //Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
         inBitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer);
         //return inBitmap ;
         // return Bitmap.createBitmap(bt, w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
         inBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bt, w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

         ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
         inBitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bos); 
         byte[] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();
         ByteArrayInputStream fis = new ByteArrayInputStream(bitmapdata);

         final Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
         long mytimestamp=c.getTimeInMillis();
         String timeStamp=String.valueOf(mytimestamp);
         String myfile="hari"+timeStamp+".jpeg";

         dir_image=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+
           "printerscreenshots"+File.separator+"image");
         dir_image.mkdirs();

         try {
            File tmpFile = new File(dir_image,myfile); 
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tmpFile);

            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            while ((len = fis.read(buf)) > 0) {
               fos.write(buf, 0, len);
            }
            fis.close();
            fos.close();
         } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }

         Log.v("hari", "screenshots:"+dir_image.toString());
      }
   } catch(Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace() ;
   }
}
```

Please Any one help me..

Thanks Advance